# ajax post of form and validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Does ajax post supports the usual validation upon submit of a form?

Is

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
@Hml.ValidationSummary()

<input type="submit" value ="Save">
}
```

same as

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm(new {id=FormTest})){
     @Hml.ValidationSummary()
<input type="button" value= Save>
    }

<script type="javascript">
$("#Save").click(function(){
$("#FormTest").submit();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it does support the validation.

Comment: Ho do I display the error messages?

Comment: Enabled client-side validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many wrong things going on here that I really don't know where to start.

1. Your `Html.BeginForm` definition is wrong: you are confusing `routeValues` with `htmlAttributes`. See below for solution
2. Your button doesn't have an id so your javascript selector will most probably fail
3. All those efforts are not necessary because a simple `<input type="submit">` button does it out of the box.

Now lets suppose that somehow you are a fan of javascript and you want to write it (I don't know why would you want to write code but anyway). So start by fixing your form definition:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormTest" }))    
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo)

    <input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" />
}
```

and then you could do this:

```
$('#Save').click(function() {
    var form = $('#FormTest');
    if (form.valid()) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

obviously you must ensure that the client scripts are properly included on your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and of course the real solution I would recommend you is to use a submit button for submitting forms:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormTest" }))    
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" />
}
```

Now you don't need any javascript (obviously you still need the two script inclusions for the unobtrusive validation).